# Duplicate cannot be flagged because "original" has no answer

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Example: ["original"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180305/how-to-implement-a-distance-method), [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203522/finding-a-valid-path-in-prolog), [triplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218148/user-defined-inputs-in-prolog).

Flagging is not possible, because there is no answer. What shall I do?

Comment: Are you *sure* these are duplicates? Same assignment maybe, but one appears to have broken down the problem to one troublesome step, while the other...

Comment: I cannot see much difference, for in both cases you would have to address the entire problem.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is deliberate:

> The fundamental goal of closing [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) is to help
> people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one
> place.

You can't flag a question as a duplicate if doing so doesn't point them to an answer to their question.

Your options are to:

- Answer one of them yourself and then flag the other as a duplicate
- Wait for someone else to answer one and then flag the other as a duplicate
- Do nothing.

We're talking about unanswered questions so if they also have a score of zero, [the system will automatically delete them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) anyway.

Comment: Yes, sure, that is theoretically possible. What happens in the real world is that questions get asked again and again.

Comment: @GhostCat That happens whether there's a duplicate or not...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I ran into a question this morning that was almost an exact copy of another question ...without an answer. I could have closed out that new immediately. Err, no, I couldn't: because the other one didnt have an answer. But what is the point of having multiple such things hang around? When you encounter a DUP, you should be able to get rid of the duplication. It is almost as if we were talking about duplicated code...