# Reposted question but cannot select original

Tags: support, flags, triage

I am a bit new to triage, so I still have some doubts in some cases.

I just found this situation:

A user is reposting an older question to get attention (they explicitly said this!). I thought the right thing was to flag the question as a duplicate but, since the original question has no answers or votes, the flag is not accepted by the system.

All other options for closing seem inappropriate, so I wonder what the expected action is here.

I have seen this other [very similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294152/duplicate-cannot-be-flagged-because-original-has-no-answer) (answer: this is ok, you can't use a question without answer to flag a duplicate since this does not provide an answer), but I think what I describe is different, because I am talking about deliberate reposting of the exact same thing, not incidental duplication (which may not be as bad because it describes a similar problem in other words, for example, which may help to get new answers).

Comment: Sorry, I lost the link (I skipped the question). It was not the same OP, it was a different person reposting it to get attention.

Comment: Of course, "in need of moderator intervention" is the way to do this, right? I had assumed this was used for other situations, but it makes sense thinking back.

Comment: If you skipped it, you can possibly still find it on the [review history page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true).

Comment: I had not even seen that tab before. I'm not feeling really clever right now, haha. But you helped me quite a bit, thanks!

Comment: @Pablo it took me at least a year to realise it's there. So you are not alone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the question is by the same person you can flag as a duplicate whether or not there are answers.

If the question is identical and not by the same person you'd have to use a custom moderator flag and explain what's happening. Moderators are not subject matter experts in all topics though so it needs to be clear to someone unfamiliar with the subject that the questions really are duplicates.

As TiiJ7 says, if you skipped the question and need to go back it will be in your [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true)